# Odometry source not changing to encoder on differential drive plugin

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am trying to simulate a simple differential drive robot (based on examples given) and I need to simulate the kidnapped robot problem. I have set the odometry source to 0 (encoder), but every time I move the robot model in gazebo, the odometry resets to the actual position of the robot regardless.

I checked the joint states for the two wheel joints, and they don't reset when I move the robot, so I am not sure why the odometry resets.

The code for my differential drive controller is given below.

Thanks!

```
<plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
        
            <update_rate>30</update_rate>
    
            <!-- Wheel Information -->
            <left_joint>left_wheel_joint</left_joint>
            <right_joint>right_wheel_joint</right_joint>
            <wheel_separation>0.35</wheel_separation>
            <wheel_diameter>0.1</wheel_diameter>
    

            <!-- Limits -->
            <max_wheel_torque>200</max_wheel_torque>
            <max_wheel_acceleration>10.0</max_wheel_acceleration>
    

            <!-- Output -->
            <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
            <robot_base_frame>base_link</robot_base_frame>
            
            <!-- Odometry source, 0 for ENCODER, 1 for WORLD, defaults to WORLD -->
            <odometrySource>0</odometrySource>
            
            
            <command_topic>cmd_vel</command_topic>
            

            <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
            <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
            <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>
            
    
    
        </plugin>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412965/odometry-source-not-changing-to-encoder-on-differential-drive-plugin/) by [ALNA_Perera](https://answers.ros.org/users/123880/alna_perera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2023-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out. Turns out it should be <odometry_source> not  despite the latter being in the tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [ALNA_Perera](https://answers.ros.org/users/123880/alna_perera/) with karma: 33 on 2023-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0